# Universe of discourse in quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am reading "How to prove it" by Velleman and am currently in the chapter about quantifiers. I don't understand why
$$
\exists x \in A (P(x))
$$
is equivalent to
$$\exists x~(x\in A \wedge P(x)),
$$
whereas
$$
\forall x \in A (P(x))
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\forall x~ (x\in A \rightarrow P(x)).
$$

I don't understand why for the existential quantifier the two statements are "anded" whereas for the universal quantifier the conditional is used.

Comment: Negate and compare.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok when I negate I get the following $\neg \forall x (x\in A \rightarrow P(x))$ is equivaltant to $\exists x (x\in A \land \neg P(x))$ How does this help? I can see that I have an and inside now.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok I get it now. because now I can pull out the the first to get $\exists x \in A(\neg P(x))$ which is equivalent to $\neg \forall x \in A (P(x))$ and then I negate on the initial statement and this statement to see that they are same. Am I right? This is really beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: Precisely! And all this is consistent with $\neg[\forall x\in A(P(x))]$ being equivalent to $\exists x\in A\neg P(x).$ But I see my reply to your first comment comes too late. Perfect!

Comment: Fun fact: If you accept that there exists no universal set (see Russell's Paradox) then $\exists x:[ x\in A \implies P]$ is true for any set $A$ and proposition $P$. Care should be taken when applying set theoretic existential quantifiers like this to conditionals.

Comment: ... Similarly, if $\exists x: \neg P(x)$ then $\exists x: [P(x) \implies Q]$ is true for any proposition $Q$.

Comment: ... Moral of the story: An existential quantifier on a conditional should set off alarm bells. It would quite possibly be the result of an error.

Comment: ... A similar argument holds for $\forall x: [x \in A \land P]$ which is always false.

Comment: @DanChristensen That sounds very interesting. I am not sure I understand though. Why is the statement $\exists x :[x\in A \rightarrow P]$ always true and the statement $\forall x : [x\in A \land P]$ always false?

Comment: Since you ask: Formal proofs https://www.dcproof.com/ExistentialQuantifierOnConditionalTrue.htm
https://www.dcproof.com/UniversalQuantifierOnConditionalFalse.htm

Answer (score 1):

$\exists x\in A~\big(P(x)\big)$ versus $\exists x~\big(x\in A\land P(x)\big)$

Some apples are peeled.    Somethings are apples and peeled.

$\forall x\in A~\big(P(x)\big)$ versus $\forall x~\big(x\in A\to P(x)\big)$

All apples are peeled.   All things are peeled when they are apples.